# From one line to regular For loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have the following For loop in one line:

```
var = ''.join('%02x' % ord(b) for b in string_var)
```

How is it displayed in a regular for loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using slow string concatenation:

```
var = ''
for b in string_var:
    var += '%02x' % ord(b)
```

What you have there is a [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions); it really produces a sequence to pass to the `str.join()` method. `''.join()` concatenates the sequence into a string with an empty delimiter.

To use the `''.join()` call you could build a list first:

```
results = []
for b in string_var:
    results.append('%02x' % ord(b))
var = ''.join(results)
```

or use a generator *function* to do the same:

```
def to_hex(lst):
    for b in lst:
        yield '%02x' % ord(b)

var = ''.join(to_hex(string_var))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is less efficient than `join`, as it forces Python to allocate memory for a new string each time you do `+=`, but it still works

```
var = ''
for b in string_var:
    var += '%02x' % ord(b)
```

Also, you can speed up your code by turning `join`'s argument into `list`:

```
var = ''.join(['%02x' % ord(b) for b in string_var])
```

**Probably the easiest way** to accomplish that is by using [`binascii.hexlify`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify):

```
from binascii import hexlify 
var = hexlify('uhh'.encode())
```